# LocalStorage variables are not detected until I manually reload the page in Angular

Tags: angular, local-storage

I have a login component which upon successful validation redirects a user to the dashboard page.

```
// save user in local storage
localStorage.setItem('authenticatedUser', JSON.stringify(rs.data));
this.router.navigate(['dashboard/dashboard-home']);
```

In the dashboard component i try to pic the user from local storage like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._authenticatedUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authenticatedUser'));
}
```

The problem is, `this._authenticatedUser` is not initially populated when a user is redirected to the page, but when the user refreshes the page, the information is there.

**NGREDUX SOLUTION**
I have done some reading and solutions like redux are a better robust approach, but aren't there other ways I can instantly share objects in Angular easily?

Comment: You can make a service which you share across your login and dashboard components.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a service which holds the user variable, instead of using the localStorage. Your user variable will then always be in the cache and accessible from any components that injects the service. Here's how you do it:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
    private _authenticatedUser: User;

    constructor(public router: Router) { }


    set user(data) {
        this._authenticatedUser = data
    }

    get user() {
        return this._authenticatedUser;
    }


    login(username, password) {
        // your authentication code
        this.authenticatedUser = rs.data
        this.router.navigate(['dashboard/dashboard-home']);
    } 

}
```

Then, in your dashboard component:

```
import { AuthenticationService } from 'wherever_its_located'

@Component
export class Dashboard implements OnInit {
    private _authenticatedUser;

    constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.__authenticatedUser = auth.authenticatedUser;
    }
}
```

I've missed some imports and minor stuff, but this is the idea.